# python facebook insights error

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

i use the following code to authenticate a facebook login

```
        import os
        import facebookinsights as fi
        pages = fi.authenticate(
        client_id='app_id', 
        client_secret='app_secret_id')
```

but i receive the following error after manually logging in

> Authentication flow completed. You may close the browser tab.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/User/Documents/tt.py", line 5, in 
>       client_secret='app_secret_id'   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookinsights__init__.py",
>   line 35, in authenticate
>       return [graph.Page(token) for token in tokens]   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookinsights__init__.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       return [graph.Page(token) for token in tokens]   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\facebookinsights\graph.py",
>   line 366, in **init**
>       self.username = data['username'] KeyError: 'username'

any solution about this error?

Comment: Have you looked at the Facebook python-SDK repository on github? You will have to look through there to find out what the structure is actually like because the documentation is ridiculously maintained (read nonexistent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page = fi.authenticate(token='pageaccesstoken')